# QT how to trigger signal outside the thread class

Tags: multithreading, qt, triggers, signals

I define  a  thread  class  ,how  to  trigger  signal in  other  class A outside the thread class.
thread class(TestThread.h):

```
#pragma once
#ifndef TESTTHREAD_H  
#define TESTTHREAD_H  

#include <QThread>  
#include "msg.h"
#include"ConverOSGB.h"
class TestThread : public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT;
public:
   explicit TestThread(QObject *parent = 0);
protected:
   void run();


 signals:
   //void TestSignal(int);
     void TTestSignal(msg);
 public:
   msg mmsg;
 private slots:
   void showMainmsg(int);

};
#endif // TESTTHREAD_H
```

TestThread.cpp:

```
#include "TestThread.h"
TestThread::TestThread(QObject *parent) :
   QThread(parent)
{
}

void TestThread::run()
{
   Myclass A  =new Myclass()
   A.fun(); // how to  emit signal  in  class  A ?

 }
void TestThread::showMainmsg(int b)
{
    mmsg.int_value = b;
    emit TTestSignal(mmsg);
}
```

how  to  trigger  signal  in Myclass A.fun?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a slot in Myclass which gets triggered when the signal is emitted from thread class, which in turn does the necessary action.